# Error when installing visual basic studio enterprise 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-10

I receive an error message when trying to install Visual Basic Studio Enterprise (see screenshot) on windows 10. I have the log file attached. I had no problems installing visual basic express (deinstalling express and then enterprise didn't work, also turning off firewall/virusscanner didn't work). Anybody an idea what I could try?

thanks,

[screenshot of error](http://www.basdohmen.com/files/dd_vs_enterprise_20160331000906.log)

[log file](http://www.basdohmen.com/files/dd_vs_enterprise_20160331000906.log)

[image]

Comment: Please inline the screenshot and the log and also provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to rename the following folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18\

to something like \Org-S-1-5-18\

Windows recreated the folder with appropriate permissions and the installation continued without error.